# rsync fail because of file permission

Tags: rsync

I was using a dual boot system and backing up in Linux my files using rsync and link-dedt and everything was working perfectly. Because the computer is mostly logged in Windows I decided to install cygwin and try to use rsync to do my backups. That way I can have a script that runs automatically every week. However when I tried to continue my backup using link-dest in cygdrive it didn't work. I think is because the files permission are seen differently by cygwin and Linux.

My command was something like:

```
 rsync -av --exclude-from=exclude.txt --progress --link-dest=/cygdrive/e/2016-02-19/ /cygdrive/d/Users/ /cygdrive/e/2016-02-24/
```

I looked at files that I knew didn't change in the link-dest and source location and everything looks the same except for the file persmission. How can I omit permissions or solve this problem?

Answer (score 0):

Cygwin on windows does cause lots of strange permissions.

If i was backing windows to a linux host, i would use https://acrosync.com/ which is native rsync for windows, unfortunately it does cost money.

We gave up on cygwin rsync partially due to these issues and ended up developing our own windows replication tool http://www.yintersync.net. Its free for non-commercial use.